# GridViewColumn Binding of ListBoxItem vs ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, listbox

I've been messing around with `GridViews` and came across an odd behavior with bindings to `GridViewColumns`.

With this XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lv">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

why does the following display the data:

```
public class Foo : ListBoxItem {               // ListBoxItem
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        lv.Items.Add(new Foo { firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe" });
        lv.Items.Add(new Foo { firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Smith" });
    }
}
```

while the following **does not** display the data:

```
public class Foo : ListViewItem {              // ListViewItem
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        lv.Items.Add(new Foo { firstName = "John", lastName = "Doe" });
        lv.Items.Add(new Foo { firstName = "Jane", lastName = "Smith" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why does the following display the data ... while the following does not display the data

Because the `ListView` control doesn't generate any `ListViewItem` container for a `ListViewItem`. For all other types of objects that you add to the `Items` or `ItemsSource` collections, an implicit `ListViewItem` container is generated.

Please refer to  [this blog post](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/item-containers/.) for more information about item containers.